# Google Contacts sync with iPhone 3G (iOS 4) without EAS

Tags: iphone, ios, google

I'm setting up an old iPhone 3G (latest iOS 4.x.x) and I'd like to sync contacts with Google.

Exchange ActiveSync (EAS) is no longer an option, and you can't use CardDAV on a pre-iOS 5 device ( http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4872 , http://support.google.com/mail/answer/2753077 ).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the iTunes sync feature ( http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1296 ) with Google Contacts.

It works pretty flawlessly, with the only (huge) downside that you can't sync without the PC.

Answer (score 0):

iOS [can do it now](http://support.google.com/a/users/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740). Though, it does not sync contact groups.

- [Sync in a Blink](http://www.syncinablink.com/) works great - it's able to sync groups.
- [Contacts Sync For Google Gmail](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contacts-sync-for-google-gmail/id454390333?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) also syncs groups.

Comment: The Google way is EAS-based and (as stated) is for Google Apps for Business, Education, and Government users only. The other two apps are worth a shot, thanks!